# How to get correct JSON format of my playlist videos in YouTube in Android?

Tags: android, json

I working with an app to show you tube videos in a listview, but I didn't get the correct format of JSON.

```
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
         Log.e("json Object : " +json);

        JSONArray jsonArray  = json.getJSONArray("items");
        Log.e("json Array is  : " +jsonArray);

        List<Video> videos = new ArrayList<Video>();

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String title = jsonObject.getString("title");

            String url;
            try {
                url = jsonObject.getJSONObject("player").getString("mobile");
            } catch (JSONException ignore) {
                url = jsonObject.getJSONObject("player").getString("default");
            }

            String thumbUrl = jsonObject.getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("sqDefault");


            videos.add(new Video(title, url, thumbUrl));
        }
```

Comment: can you please print your log here

Comment: What is JSON that you want to create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, I got the answer and i would like to share with you guys.

```
     String response = getUrlString(url);

     JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.toString());

     JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("items");

     for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

     JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

     JSONObject video = jsonObject.getJSONObject("snippet").getJSONObject("resourceId");
     String title = jsonObject.getJSONObject("snippet").getString("title");
     String id = video.getString("videoId");
     String thumbUrl = jsonObject.getJSONObject("snippet").getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("default").getString("url");
     displaylist = new Videos(title, thumbUrl ,id);
     displaylistArray.add(displaylist);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are new (fresher) to the android development. Let me share couple of good practices to implement json parsing in android development.

1. First use [JsonScheme2Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.or), put your json and create a POJO class
2. Use GSON library, in which you will just require to use couple of methods to parse json and get list of POJO objects.